# Point a Server Using Domain From Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, reverse-dns

we have a server machine with Debian 9 installed. It has an internal knowledge base website which the domain is kb.domain.com with the local IP of 192.168.1.95.

Currently we have a new installed Windows Server 2016 with DNS role. I don't know if this possible or not, but what we really want to achieve is when we access that kb.domain.com through browser we will be directed to it, but the entire configuration are set in Windows Server 2016 side.

Usually we need to change every user's hosts file in system32 to access this site.
Is it possible? What is the step for doing so?

Thank you.

Comment: why is this question got downvoted? did i breaking rules?

Comment: I am not sure, but this link might help you. https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask For example, what section of the product documentation did you read? What did you try and what problem/error are you experiencing? Good questions require effort to solve first. I do not advise just creating a question without effort, research and details.

Comment: This reads like ... you just want to create a DNS record on your Windows DNS Server?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you need to set up the following (very common and standard) things:

1. Make sure your DNS server is set up as a recursive resolver or forwarder, so that hosts can resolve Internet sites through it
2. If you have a Windows domain, make sure your DNS server knows about it and can resolve names in it
3. Instead of whatever your router is now giving out as DNS servers (or whatever you may have statically configured), have your router give out the IP addresses of your DNS server you set up
4. Make a DNS record on that server that points at your web server's IP address
5. Restore all the hosts' HOSTS files to the factory default, or at least remove the entry for your webserver.

The point here is... essentially, computers only have one view of DNS, provided by their DNS servers.  If you want to set up your own DNS records you have to have your computers resolve through your own DNS server, which you set up.  It has to provide all the DNS records they need, including ones from the Internet and ones from your AD domain if you have one.

I'd suggest, very strongly, reading up on how DNS works and trying this in a lab.